# How to store and share one single Pusher instance

Tags: reactjs, pusher, pusher-js

I've read that using multiple instances of Pusher is not recommended and therefore I am using React's context feature.

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import Pusher from "pusher-js";

const PusherContext = React.createContext<Pusher | undefined>(undefined);
export const usePusher = () => useContext(PusherContext)

export const PusherProvider: React.FC = (props) => {
    const clientRef = useRef<Pusher>();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!clientRef.current) {
            clientRef.current = new Pusher('pusher_key', {
                cluster: 'pusher_cluster',
                authEndpoint: 'auth_endpoint',
            })
        }
    }, [clientRef]);

    return (
        <PusherContext.Provider value={clientRef?.current}>
            {props.children}
        </PusherContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

Our pusher instance is of type `Pusher` or `undefined`. When we call `usePusher` it is always undefined.

```
import { usePusher } from "./services/pusher";


const Chat: React.FC = (props) => {
    const pusher = usePusher()
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if (pusher) {
            console.log("pusher is initialized/defined")
        } else {
            // it is always undefined
            console.log("pusher is not initialized/defined")
        }
    }, [pusher])

    return (
        <div>
            Test component
        </div>
    )
}
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Could use React Context https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html `Context is designed to share data that can be considered “global” for a tree of React components`

Comment: I did, but I have a problem and it will be great if I get some help to fix it.

Comment: What is this syntax called object?.element ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work. I was just doing something wrong when wrapping the provider. Hope it helps in case someone have similar problem!